# Cannot blast database created with blastdb_aliastool: BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found

Tags: blast, makeblastdb

I want to merge/concatenate BLAST databases as suggested [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/7386/merging-concatentating-blast-databases).

This is my example script that explains what I'm trying to achieve better than words can:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in FAM1079.ffn FAM3228.ffn FAM6161.ffn FAM19036.ffn
do
    echo "## Make DB for $file"
 makeblastdb -in $file -dbtype nucl &>/dev/null
    blastn -db $file  -query query_single_nucl.fasta -outfmt 6
    echo
done

echo "## Create testdb.nal..."
blastdb_aliastool -dblist "FAM1079.ffn FAM3228.ffn FAM6161.ffn FAM19036.ffn" -dbtype nucl -title test -out testdb

echo
echo "## Test testdb.nal..."
blastn -db testdb.nal -query query_single_nucl.fasta -outfmt 6
```

This is the output:

```
## Make DB for FAM1079.ffn
test_query  FAM1079_00001   100.000 1266    0   0   1   1266    1   1266    0.0 2338

## Make DB for FAM3228.ffn
test_query  FAM3228_000001  100.000 1266    0   0   1   1266    1   1266    0.0 2338

## Make DB for FAM6161.ffn
test_query  FAM6161_000001  100.000 1266    0   0   1   1266    1   1266    0.0 2338

## Make DB for FAM19036.ffn
test_query  FAM19036p_000001    100.000 1266    0   0   1   1266    1   1266    0.0 2338

## Create testdb.nal...
Created nucleotide BLAST (alias) database testdb with 12692 sequences

## Test testdb.nal...
BLAST Database error: No alias or index file found for nucleotide database [testdb.nal] in search path [/path/to/files::]
```

While the individual databases work, the concatenated databases don't.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the database must be specified without suffix, i.e. `blastn -db testdb` as opposed to `blastn -db testdb.nal`.

By the way, it produces exactly the same output as

```
blastn -db "FAM1079.ffn FAM3228.ffn FAM6161.ffn FAM19036.ffn" -query query_single_nucl.fasta -outfmt 6
```

and the performance is not better.